# Extended height of washing machine drain hose on a short laundry tub

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

Extended height of washing machine drain hose on a short laundry tub.

I have a Maytag washing machine giving me a LO FO error. I’ve tried clean the filters and running the Affresh cleaning solution but I still get the same error. I think the issue is the laundry tub is at 32” high and needs to be at 39” What is a clean/good way to extend the height of the drain hose to fix this issue.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: LO FO sounds more like not enough water going in than out.  Have you checked the flow of water going into the washer?  The drain pipe just needs to be raised up if that is the problem, a couple of pieces of string/wire to keep it in place for testing.

Comment: I took off the inflow water hoses and they produce a lot of flow. I cleaned the filter too not too dirty but I still have the same error message.